# opencv, shared libraries missing

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries

I have a opencv application that is built using shared libraries. When I run it in another computer that does not have opencv. There are a warning "error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4".

My question is how I can move libopencv_core.so.2.4 along with my application so that I can run my application.

I try to place libopencv_core.so.2.4 in the same folder with my application. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy libopencv_core.so.2.4.?.dylib  not libopencv_core.so.2.4.dylib

the libopencv_core.so.2.4.dylib is just a symbol link.